# CSS grid does not collapse cell in response to img transform

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a css `grid` with two cells, holding some text and an image. The cells are repositioned depending on the screen width, using a media query.

If `max-width = 500px` is true, the image is placed on top of the text. Otherwise, the image is placed to the right of the text. I also scale the image with `transform: scale(0.5)` in the media query.

All of this works fine, except that when the image is scaled, the grid cell that is containing it remains at the original dimension of the image. In other words, the cell does not collapse to the scaled size of the image.

If instead of using `transform` I modify the image dimensions using a relative `width` and `height`, the grid cell collapses. However, these dimensions will be relative to the image container and that's not what I want.

Perhaps `transform: scale()` does not trigger a redraw of the grid. The script below exemplifies the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

```css
.adaptive-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    justify-items: center;    
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    grid-auto-columns: min-content;
}

.adaptive-grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.adaptive-grid .left {
 grid-column: 1;
}

.adaptive-grid .right {
    grid-column: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .adaptive-grid {
     grid-template-rows: auto auto;
     grid-template-columns: auto;
 }
 
 .adaptive-grid .first {
     grid-row: 1;
     grid-column: 1;
 }
 
 .adaptive-grid .second {
     grid-row: 2;
     grid-column: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .img_50 {
      transform: scale(0.5);
      /*width: 20%;
      height: 20%;*/
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="adaptive-grid">
  <div class="left second">
    <p>
    some html
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right first">
    <img class="img_50" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformations do not affect layout. They happen in another layer. This has nothing to do with CSS Grid.

You can observe this more simply:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.element {
  background: #ddd;
  transform: translateY(50px)
}

.no-transform {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="no-transform">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the `transform` to the image itself, why not add it to the container?

```
.right.first {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

This causes the container to shrink, and because the container shrinks, so does the image within:

```css
.adaptive-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
}

.adaptive-grid>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.adaptive-grid .left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.adaptive-grid .right {
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .adaptive-grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
  .adaptive-grid .first {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .adaptive-grid .second {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .right.first {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="adaptive-grid">
  <div class="left second">
    <p>
      some html
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right first">
    <img class="img_50" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try this before and unfortunately it does not help. While the container and the image both scale, the vertical space in the container cell is not collapsed. When you use `width` and `height` dimensioning, the vertical space collapses and the text is moved up right below the image.